# Splice an array in react keeps removing the first element

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, splice

Working on my todo app, when I want to remove an element from an array, it keeps removing the first element all the time...
I cant find why.

Any ideas? I copy the bit of code that is linked to my remove function !

THANK YOU!

```js
function App () {

  const [activities, setActivities] = useState([]);
  const [color, setColor] = useState ('Black');
  const [complete, setComplete] = useState([]);
 

  //ADD NEW ACTIVITY

  /* activities*/

  function addActivity (data) {
    let newActivity = { data, done:false, isMotivating: false, id: sum , color: 'Black' }
    sum++;
    setActivities((activities) => [ ...activities, newActivity])
    //console.log(`App: ${JSON.stringify(data)}`)
      };
    


  function toggleColor (a)  {
    setColor ('')
    activities[a.id].isMotivating =  activities[a.id].isMotivating ? false : true

        if (activities[a.id].isMotivating === false) {
        setColor ('green')
        activities[a.id].color = color
    } else {
        setColor ('red')
        activities[a.id].color = color
    }
        console.log(activities[a.id])
        return activities;
    } 

    function removeTodo (id ) {
      const newTodos = [...activities];
      newTodos.splice(id, 1);
      setActivities(newTodos);
    };
}
```

Comment: Where do you call `removeTodo`?

Comment: we can't help unless you show the jsx returned. Likely you aren't passing the correct `id` to `removeTodo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `sum` seems to be declared via `let/var` which will be initialized to 0 on each re-render so each of your `id` is probably set to 0.

You can instead use `useRef` like so :-

`const uuid = useRef(0);`

Inside `addActivity`

```
function addActivity (data) {
    let newActivity = { data, done:false, isMotivating: false, id:uuid.current , color: 'Black' }
    uuid.current++;
    setActivities((activities) => [ ...activities, newActivity])
    //console.log(`App: ${JSON.stringify(data)}`)
      };
```

But not sure if using `id` as `index` to splice is best way to go here since you're always removing stuff, your array length will change.

Comment: Hi there :) 

Thanks for the help here is the JSX 

<DraggableItem id = "drag_1" className='DraggableItem' draggable = 'true'  key={0}> 
               (...)
                    </ul>  
               </div>
               <button id="removeBtn" onClick={() => removeTodo(a)}> Delete </button>
 
               </li>
               </DraggableItem>